# Updating a D3 Map sample

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, esri-leaflet, esri-oss

I spotted a nice [D3 Map & Chart sample](http://bl.ocks.org/tnightingale/4718717) that is using

- leaflet-0.5
- d3.v3

I would like to make use of some features in the esri-leaflet package ([specifically use a Vector basemap](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/vector-basemap.html)), but I believe I need to update the current sample to leaflet-1.2.0 to do this.

As soon as I switch from using leaflet-0.5 to the leaflet@1.2.0 (from the vector sample) in the header, along with the latest CSS then I get the following error in the console:

```
leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: The provided object is not a Layer.
at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:5)
at e.addTo (leaflet.points-layer.js:44)
at d3_map_vt.html:76
at d3.v3.js:2011
at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v3.js:1996)
at Object.event (d3.v3.js:504)
at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.v3.js:1949)
```

Can someone give me some pointers on how to go about updating this sample and what the cause of the above error is?  Do I need to also update the d3 library as well?

I have tweaked the code for my own data [here](http://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/languagesofaustralia.com/SimonJacksonFiles/d3/d3_map.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're in luck. that great sample only requires one small tweak to run in Leaflet 1.x.

```
// line 1 of leaflet.points-layer.js
L.PointsLayer = L.Layer.extend({ // instead of L.Class    
  includes: L.Evented.prototype, // instead of L.Mixin.Events
```